# How to check if clicked in jquery

Tags: jquery

i am trying to check the if the element clicked. if element is already clicked, skip this step or else do this step.for this i am using jquery but i am not able get how can i do it...

code:

```
$('.f').click(function(evt) { 
                    $('#ex4').trigger('click'); 
                                var idx = $(this).attr('id').substr(1); 
                                ipx=$('#b'+idx).offset().left; 
                                ipy=$('#b'+idx).offset().top; 
                                $('#ex4').trigger('click'); 
                                ipx=0; 
                                ipy=0;
                                $(".target").html($($(this).attr('href')).html());
                            });
```

in this code, i want to check that if `$('#ex4').trigger('click');` is clicked? if have already clicked, then skip this line '`$('#ex4').trigger('click');`' or else execute that line now. '`$('#ex4').trigger('click');`' how can i do this?

Comment: Which element is clicked?

Comment: @Kannan if #ex4 is triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends exactly what you need to achieve.

The most general solution, use a boolean flag:

```
var ex4clicked = false;

$('.f').click(function (evt) {
    if(ex4clicked === false) {
        $('#ex4').trigger('click');
        ex4clicked = true;
    }
    var idx = $(this).attr('id').substr(1);
    ipx = $('#b' + idx).offset().left;
    ipy = $('#b' + idx).offset().top;
    $('#ex4').trigger('click');
    ipx = 0;
    ipy = 0;
    $(".target").html($($(this).attr('href')).html());
});
```

That's one click for *any* click on a `.f` element; if you want one click *per* `.f` element you'd need to tie the flag to each of the elements, likely using data:

```
<element class="f" data-clicked="false">some text</element>

$('.f').click(function(e) {
    var ex4clicked = $(this).data('clicked');
    if(ex4clicked === false) {
        $('#ex4').trigger('click');
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
    }
    // rest of your code
});
```

Another option, if you're using jQuery to bind the click event handler on `#ex4` and only want one click per page load, is to simply use a one-time event handler:

```
$('#ex4').one('click', function(e) {
    // some code
});
```

That will unbind itself after the first time it's executed, meaning subsequent `$('#ex4').trigger('click');` calls won't result in that particular event handler firing again.

Answer (score 1):

Use something different.
eg:

```
 $("#ex4").click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('clicked_obj'))
  {
    // Is already clicked Do something
   }else{
         $(this).addClass('clicked_obj');
         // is not clicked do somthing
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a boolean to false until the element is clicked :

```
var clicked = false;

$('#ex4').click(function(){
    clicked = true;
})

$('.f').click(function(){
    if(!clicked) $('#ex4').trigger('click');
})
```